# How to set default value in a dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have the following code :

```
 render: function (data, type, product) {
                            var s = $('<select id="qty_dropdown" />');
                            for (i = 1; i <= data; i++) {
                                $('<option />', { value: i, text: i }).appendTo(s);
                            }
                            $('#qty_dropdown>option:eq('+data+')').prop('selected', true);
                            return s.prop("outerHTML");

                        }
```

I am simply trying to set the selected value  = data. However, this displays the first option value instead of the last option value. So for example, if data == 10, then the dropdown displays 1 instead of 10. Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more descriptive than "does not work"

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: `eq()` is not used for comparison.  It is used to get a specific element at a position.  Such as `eq(0)` would get the first element.

Comment: So if data == 10 and I want to select 10 as the selected option, then I would have to just do data -1 in eq right?

Comment: If the first element has a value of 1, and onwards increasing for each element, sure.

Comment: Though given your loop, the data will always be the last element...  You could potentially just do `:last`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the element you are trying to select is the last one, you can just update it.

```js
var data = 10;
var s = $('<select id="qty_dropdown" />');
for (i = 1; i <= data; i++) {
  $('<option />', {
    value: i,
    text: i
  }).appendTo(s);
}
//You need to perform the find on the `s` element, not on the page
s.find('option:last').attr('selected', true);
console.log(s.prop("outerHTML"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#qty_dropdown option[value="'+data+'"]').prop('selected', true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the dropdown is a newly created element and it is not part of the DOM you cannot use:

```
$('#qty_dropdown>option:eq('+data+')').prop('selected', true);
```

Instead, you can use the variable:

```
s.find('option:eq('+(data-1)+')').prop('selected', true);
```

You need to use **data - 1** because the options in a dropdown go from 0 to n -1

In any case the simplest way to select an option in a dropdown is [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/):

```js
var data = 10;

var s = $('<select id="qty_dropdown" />');
for (i = 1; i <= data; i++) {
    $('<option />', { value: i, text: i }).appendTo(s);
}
s.val(data);
// just to see ...
s.appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```